# Quantitative Method Comparison & Experimental Error

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I'm a Y1 Chem Undergrad and I standardised hydrogen peroxide using two different methods (both redox titrations) in the lab. This was done to compare the 2 different methods and their reliability. I am unsure how to quantitatively evaluate/compare them as there is no 'theoretical' H2O2 conc., just the experimental values you get.

The methods give [H2O2] conc. = 12x10^-3, 9x10^-3 (gL^-1). I thought I *might* be able to calculate the percentage error if I assumed the mean was the 'theoretical' value (gives ~22%) but this seems like a bit of a cop-out to me. Random errors for the titrations are 3.2% and 0% respectively.

Is there a statistical technique you are aware of that might allow me to quantitatively compare my results?

Many thanks,

J

Comment: There is something called as the paired t-test that compares the two means and tells us if they belong to the same population or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’ve done multiple runs of each titration, you can work out the 95% confidence interval and the standard deviation. This can be done in excel. It would also be worth quantifying the errors from each instrument (the burette, pipette, etc.). That being said, if you already know that the random errors are different, doesn’t that already tell you one result is more reliable than another?